# mod_rewrite and % character

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite a URL that contains one or more strings of characters incling a % character (for instance %123) into another string of characters including a % character (for instance %234).

I am able to do this using the special THE_REQUEST attribute with something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)\%123(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule .* /%1\%234%2 [R,NE]
```

However, this does not work for URLs that contain more than one "%123" strings... The N option has no efect as it seems that the value of THE_REQUEST is not changed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you can only perform the substitutes in the `QUERY_STRING` part of the request.  So:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*\%)123(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1234%2 [NE,N]
```

Will rewrite a URL like:

```
/our/example?this%123is%123a%123test
```

to:

```
/our/example?this%234is%234a%234test
```

However, there is no way to perform this type of substitution for the `REQUEST_URI` part of the query.  By the time mod_rewrite receives the `REQUEST_URI` all the percent marks have been converted.  For example, if the `REQUEST_URI` contained `%12` it appears to mod_rewrite as control-R (0x12) and there does not seem to be any way of matching non-ASCII characters in mod_rewrite.